Power Automate: Outlook Email Attachment Sent as Blank
(The original Chinese text translated into English by GPT.)I used Outlook's 'Send an email (V2)' action to attach a file named 'Convert' from OneDrive. The content of the file is also 'Convert'. However, when I send the PDF, the content is blank. But I have the same file stored in SharePoint, and when I download and open it, the content is normal.
1.I saved the PDF file in OneDrive and attempted to send an email containing the PDF, but the content was blank.
2.I saved the WORD file in OneDrive and attempted to send an email containing a .docx file, but it couldn't be opened.
3.I converted the content of the PDF into base64 and stored it as a variable in the file content, but the PDF still couldn't be opened.
4.I changed all the variable file paths to "123" and also changed the content and file names to "123", but it still opened as blank.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

Show us and detail the steps in your flow along with any expressions so we can understand the specifics of what you’re doing better.

我在Micorsoft社群中找到解答了，謝謝你的關注。發送郵件中使用附件這個問題僅出現在新power automate新版(V3)中出現，將編輯畫面右上角開關關掉在執行流程就可以正常運作，我有時間會將解答、畫面與社群網址更新上來，再次謝謝你的關注。

I found the solution in the Microsoft community. Thank you for your attention. The issue of using attachments in sending emails only occurs in the new version (V3) of Power Automate. By toggling off the switch at the top right corner of the editing interface, the workflow can function normally. I will update with the solution, screenshots, and the community URL when I have time. Thank you again for your attention.

The issue of using attachments in sending emails only arises in the new version (V3) of Power Automate. To resolve this, simply toggle off the switch at the top right corner of the editing interface, and the workflow should function normally. Alternatively, in the URL of the editing page, append 'v3=false v3survey=true'.


This is an answer found within the Microsoft community, but I currently cannot locate the original URL where the answer was found.
